# android monkeyrunner python script with tkinter

Tags: android, python-3.x, tkinter, monkeyrunner

I'm using python(v3.6.0) and tkinter is working fine.
Now I'm trying to add tkinter to my python script to work with android monkeyrunner tool. When I try to execute execute below command:

```
C:\Python36\myScript>monkeyrunner C:\Python36\myScript\installApp.py
```

command, then the following error message is appeared:

```
[main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Script terminated due to an exception
[main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python36\myScript\installApp.py", line 2, in <module>
import tkinter as tk
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

I have already added my Python library file path **C:\Python36\Lib**, in my windows environment variable, but still **ImportError: No module name tkinter** error occured.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `monkeyrunner` is based on jython. You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which is almost a drop-in replacement, based on python and also uses Tkinter for the UI (see [culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI)).